# Show value only on id corresponding checkbox/div id on sucess. (Jquery,php,mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have a list of multiple updates arrays (php-mysql-jquery) with checkbox, text input new category name and category, everything working.

The categories of each item are show within a `<div>` with id equal to the checkbox. How do I get the update (after post, `on success: function`), only `<div>` with id equal to the checkbox clicked load the updated value?

`<input text="nova categoria" value="cars" />` sending value `cars` only mysql update for ckecboxes checked.

```
<td> checkbox checked id = 111 </ td> 
<td> Porshe </ td> 
<td> category id = 111 </ td> 
<td><div id=111>here show "cars"</div></td>
<td> checkbox id = 555 </ td> 
Jobs <td> </ td> 
<td> category id = 555 </ td>
<div id=111>here not show</div>
<td> checkbox checked id = 777 </ td> 
<td> Jaguar </ td> 
<td> category id = 777 </ td>  
<div id=111>here show "cars"</div>
<td> checkbox id = 888 </ td> 
<td> Café </ td> 
<td> category id = 888 </ td>
<div id=111>here not show</div>
<td> checkbox checked id = 222 </ td> 
<td> Mustang </ td> 
<td> category id = 222 </ td>
<div id=111>here show "cars"</div>
<td> checkbox checked id = 123 </ td> 
<td> Ferrari </ td> 
<td> category id = 123 </ td>
<div id=111>here show "cars"</div>
```

Please any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By giving your divs different id's. for example, give all the cars you want to show when checkbox 111 is checked, the id "111". should be shown with jquery.

so that makes `$('#111').show` ... Then you do the same for 222, 333, 444, or whatever codes you'd like to use. and if nothing is checked you use `.hide`